# Highly performant fixed size ring queue with blocking Enqueue and Dequeue

Tags: go, queue

I'm trying to create a highly performant fixed size ring queue with blocking Enqueue and Dequeue. There will be only one Producer that Enqueues items and one Subscriber that Dequeues. So thread safety is not needed in that regard. Enqueue should block until space in the buffer is released. Dequeue should also block until new items are enqueued or until the queue is closed. Produced closes the buffer when it is done. This is required to reduce memory allocation when trying to push gigabytes of datapoints through processor.

I was hoping to get close to performance that slice iteration has, but to no avail. I even asked ChatGPT and it spewed out something similar that I already had:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

type RingQueue struct {
    buffer   []int
    capacity int
    head     int
    tail     int
    size     int
    mutex    sync.Mutex
    notEmpty *sync.Cond
    notFull  *sync.Cond
}

func NewRingQueue(capacity int) *RingQueue {
    r := &RingQueue{
        buffer:   make([]int, capacity),
        capacity: capacity,
        head:     0,
        tail:     0,
        size:     0,
    }
    r.notEmpty = sync.NewCond(&r.mutex)
    r.notFull = sync.NewCond(&r.mutex)
    return r
}

func (r *RingQueue) Enqueue(val int) {
    r.mutex.Lock()
    defer r.mutex.Unlock()

    for r.size == r.capacity {
        r.notFull.Wait()
    }
    r.buffer[r.tail] = val
    r.tail = (r.tail + 1) % r.capacity
    r.size++

    r.notEmpty.Signal()
}

func (r *RingQueue) Dequeue() int {
    r.mutex.Lock()
    defer r.mutex.Unlock()

    for r.size == 0 {
        r.notEmpty.Wait()
    }
    val := r.buffer[r.head]
    r.head = (r.head + 1) % r.capacity
    r.size--

    r.notFull.Signal()

    return val
}

func TestRing(t *testing.T) {
    q := NewRingQueue(1000000)

    const items = 1000000
    go func() {
        now := time.Now()
        for i := 0; i < items; i++ {
            q.Enqueue(i)
        }
        fmt.Println("enqueue", time.Since(now))
    }()

    now := time.Now()
    count := 0
    for {
        q.Dequeue()
        count++
        if count == items {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("dequeue", time.Since(now))
}
```

On my machine producer can generate 1_000_000 datapoints in under 1ms.
With the code above it takes around 100ms to go through 1_000_000 datapoins.
If the processing pipeline has 10 transformations, it would spend at worst 1 second just on sending and receiving overhead.
On the other hand, slice iteration can occur in less than 1ms.

What can I do to reduce Enqueue/Dequeue time?

Comment: You could [benchmark](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go) `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` independently to see which is most at fault. You could also check the [profiler](https://go.dev/blog/pprof). And finally, what open-source implementations have you already tried?

Comment: Most of the time is spent locking/unlocking mutex. Since the sync.Cond uses a shared mutex I can't write if I'm reading and vice versa. I've tried everything that I can find while googling all or parts of this question title (eapache/queue, Workiva/go-datastructures, hedzr/go-ringbuf, GavinClarke0/lockless-generic-ring-buffer, cloudfoundry/go-diodes...). All of them >= 100ms per 1Mil. I got as low as 20ms with github.com/smarty-prototypes/go-disruptor I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: The mutex lock and unlock at the start of each of enqueue and dequeue are where your bottleneck comes from. It effectively turns the work into a synchronous task, and very similar to reading and writing a zero-buffer channel

Comment: I had a suspicion the synchronization was the problem. This may sound silly, but have you tried using a channel? They are basically just ring buffers under the hood and are fast. Your use case seems to match it perfectly.

Comment: @TylerKropp channels also cap at around 100ms

Comment: In production, would the circular buffer be handed 1 million elements at once? If so, then maybe you should just pass slices around!

Comment: I just mean that maybe it doesn't matter that it takes 100ms to do this. When data is being streamed from a file or a connection, that time is going to be swallowed up by I/O.
If you want a faster ring buffer, you probably have to make the API sequential. So if running each side in different goroutines is a requirement, then I have no further suggestions :(